# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebKit: Le module spécifié est introuvable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

**the code :**

- I don't know why it doesn't run at execution time, knowing that I
  downloaded all the libraries needed by the program

  ```
   from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
   from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
   from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebInspector
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSplitter, QVBoxLayout, QWidget



   class Window(QWidget):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
           self.view = QWebView(self)
           self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
           self.inspector = QWebInspector()
           self.inspector.setPage(self.view.page())
           self.inspector.show()
           self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
           self.splitter.addWidget(self.view)
           self.splitter.addWidget(self.inspector)
           layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
           layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       import sys
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       window = Window()
       window.view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
       window.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```

  ### ***after excute :***

  ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 2, in <module>
       from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
   ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebKit: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
  ```

> I don't know why it doesn't run at execution time, knowing that I
> downloaded all the libraries needed by the program

### library 1 :

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

### library 2 :

```
pip install PyQt5
```

***Is there a solution to this problem ??***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you sample uses QtWebKit, not Qt WebEngine. If you have installed pyqtwebengine then use the following code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSplitter, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        self.inspector = QWebEngineView()
        self.view.page().setDevToolsPage(self.inspector.page())
        self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.view)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.inspector)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.splitter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
but i install the library : 
pip install PyQtWebEngine

Comment: @sakomalten I recommend you uninstall all python (and its libraries) and when you reinstall it, check the option that indicates: add Python to PATH, which is the cause of your problem, see this image: https://docs.python.org/3/_images/win_installer.png